# Angular social login redirect to login screen

Tags: angular, google-oauth

When I tried to use redirect instead of popup with angularx-social-login for goolge login, not able to get response of SocialUser object with SignIn and authState.

```
this.socialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(user => {           
                this.goolgeUser = user;
                this.handleAuthenticated();
            }
       }

 this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
           if(user) {
             this.goolgeUser = user;
           }
        });
```

app.module.ts configuration for goolge

```
const googleLoginOptions = {
    ux_mode: "redirect",
    scope: xxx
    plugin_name:'login' 
};
```

Comment: where did you set ``googleLoginOptions`` ? could you please make a stackblitz?